# Log4J error is throwing after server update for tomcat 7

Tags: java, tomcat, log4j

I did update my linux sever and tomcat 7 version and it breaks the current app and throws this log4j error at the start up,

Error is:

```
log4j:ERROR Either File or DatePattern options are not set for appender
```

log4J properties file as given:

```
    log4j.rootLogger=ERROR,stdout,APP_FILE

    log4j.appender.APP_FILE=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
    log4j.appender.APP_FILE.File=/var/log/app/tomcat/Engine_log_app.log
    log4j.appender.APP_FILE.ImmediateFlush=true
    log4j.appender.APP_FILE.Threshold=debug
    log4j.appender.APP_FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.APP_FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd 
    HH:mm:ss.SSSS}| %p| %t| %c.%M|%m%n

    log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
    log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

   log4j.logger.com.app.app=DEBUG, stdout
   log4j.logger.com.app.app=INFO
   log4j.logger.org.hibernate=OFF , APP_FILE
   log4j.logger.com.zone.app=ALL, APP_FILE
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find the correct reason why it thew this specific error. But it has happened due to some security context update in linux server. I was able to resolve the issue temporarily with setenforce 0.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be because of this line? it looks like a new line character has split it in 2 lines

```
log4j.appender.APP_FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd 
HH:mm:ss.SSSS}| %p| %t| %c.%M|%m%n
```

Can you make it one-line again and check?